# Twitter boostrap 3 margin grid issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginner in twitter bootstrap My question is simple can i use my custom CSS  in bootstrap also, is it a correct way or i have to use only bootstrap classes Like i am facing margin padding issues 
For Example
i used the .container-fluid class now i want to use .wrap class of mine 
`.wrap{
   width:1249px;
   margin:0px auto;
}`
then i used the .row and .col in it suppose the first col is col-sm-4 how and in .col-sm-4 i use h1 heading it need margin from left 
the actual question is, Is it a correct way of using own classes when we need?
is it make any difference? the responsiveness will remain the same? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use your own class also along with bootstrap 3.However it might affect the responsiveness of your page, since you are fixing the width. So, if the page becomes less than 1249px, it will show a horizontal scroll.

Comment: so can i fix this if i want complete responsive what i have to do

Comment: In bootstrap 3 you can use multiple classes at same element. Eg- for mobile, use col-xs-*, for tablets  use col-sm-* , for monitors use col-md-* and for large monitors use col-lg-*

Comment: Also make sure if you want a fix width, container-fluid should be inside it. It will inherit the width and all the inner elements will inherit the width accordingly.

Comment: `
     <div class="container-fluid">
        
    <div class="row" id="bg-color">
    <div id="wraper">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                         
                          <h1 id=""><a href="#" id="text-color">Just Write</a></h1>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `

Comment: obviously i am using these classes for grid for sectioning

Comment: Actually this is not very correct. For improvement, if you know that a particular section is going to take 100%, just use col-xs-12 , it will take the width automatically in other views. Use other classes only if you want to give different width in different views.

Comment: <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row" id="bg-color"> <div id="wraper"> <div class="col-xs-12"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-4"> <h1 id=""><a href="#" id="text-color">Just Write</a></h1> </div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-xs-12"> </div> </div> </div>